# CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, shared-hosting

i uploaded my asp.net mvc application to godddy web hosting .and it gives me this error

CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

i uploaded my project with pre compilation but not works.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I'm afraid your question is not clear enough to help you. Please have a look at [ask]. And there's more info in the [help]. You could also have the [tour], so get a quick overview.

Comment: Likely, the server doesn't have the .net framework installed you've used to develop the app.

Comment: i added System.Runtime.dll file manually to the server in bin folder and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

i added System.Runtime.dll file manually to the server in bin folder and it worked for me